# Calculating the geographic and euclidean distances for TSP in Java

Tags: java, math, coordinates, distance, euclidean-distance

Basically I'm using data from TSPLIB and I have this  spec .

This is how I calculated the Euclidean distance (according to the above spec):

```
public static double calculateDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    double xDistance = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
    double yDistance = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
    double distance = Math.sqrt( (xDistance*xDistance) + (yDistance*yDistance) );

    return distance;
}
```

This is how I calculated the geographic distance (according to the above spec):

```
public static double calculateGeoDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double lat1Rad = coordinates2Radians(lat1);
    double lat2Rad = coordinates2Radians(lat2);
    double lon1Rad = coordinates2Radians(lon1);
    double lon2Rad = coordinates2Radians(lon2);

    double R = 6378.388;

    double q1 = Math.cos(lon1Rad - lon2Rad);
    double q2 = Math.cos(lat1Rad - lat2Rad);
    double q3 = Math.cos(lat1Rad + lat2Rad);

    double distance = (R * Math.acos(0.5 * ((1.0 + q1) * q2 - (1.0 - q1) * q3)) + 1.0);
    return distance;
}

private static double coordinates2Radians(double coordinate) {
    double deg = Math.round(coordinate);
    double min = coordinate - deg;
    double rad = Math.PI * (deg + 5.0 * min / 3.0) / 180.0; 
    // NOTE: Bug in TSPLIB95 Docu. Divide by 300 instead of 3.0.
    // 5.0 * 60 / 300 = 1 (60 minutes are 1 degree)
    // or use Math.PI * (deg in decimal) / 180.0; 
    return rad;
}
```

But this problem is that I'm getting results that are less than the TSPLIB optimal (that cant be possible!). Is there something wrong with my calculation? I have tried calculating the optimal using predefined data and distances and I do get the optimal, I'm not sure why this isnt working..

Many thanks.

Comment: a) which "above spec" are you referring to? b) Why can't the distances be shorter, compared to what is given in the TSPLIB instances? I mean, there, the distances are the ones along the possible routes, so they are obviously longer than the geographical distance between two points, aren't they?

Comment: Sorry this is the spec: http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/DOC.PS @DaDaDom

Comment: Because the optimal path is the shortest path found - I'm pretty sure it means that what I have has a bug. I just dont know how to check if my calculation is wrong.. I dont know what could be wrong @DaDaDom

Comment: Your equation doesn't look right to me.  It may be equivalent to the standard Haversine formulation, but if so, it's not a trivial transformation.  I recommend you look at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: This is a bug in the calculation. Divide by 300 instead of 3.0 to get the correct result. I commented also in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion to radians looks suspicious.  I would try:

```
private static double coordinates2Radians(double coordinate) {
    return Math.PI * coordinate / 180.0;
}
```

Also, I would use the equations at the [Movable Type](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) site I mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just used the same approach (it looks the same, dont think i missed anything) on page 7 of the spec (the link is above). I dont know what formulation is used in this spec but it doesnt look like Haversine formulation.

Comment: I am getting more reasonable results after changing the 'coorsinares2Radians' function but i dont understand why because that is not how it is calculated in the spec.. do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I am still finding paths that are less than the optimal.. really cannot understand why!

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you to read the FAQ of TSPLIB

http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/TSPFAQ.html

Check the Q: I get wrong distances for problems of type GEO.

I followed that implementation instead of what is listed in the TSPLIB 95 spec. My implementation (in Groovy):

```
static int[][] distancesInGEO(List nodes) {
    int dim = nodes.size();
    double[] latitude = new double[dim];
    double[] longitude = new double[dim];

    final double PI = 3.141592;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        int deg = (int) (nodes[i].x);
        double min = nodes[i].x - deg;
        latitude[i] = PI * (deg + 5 * min / 3) / 180;
        deg = (int) nodes[i].y;
        min = nodes[i].y - deg;
        longitude[i] = PI * (deg + 5 * min / 3) / 180;
    }

    int[][] d = new int[dim][dim];

    final double RRR = 6378.388;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < dim; j++) {
            double q1 = cos(longitude[i] - longitude[j]);
            double q2 = cos(latitude[i] - latitude[j]);
            double q3 = cos(latitude[i] + latitude[j]);
            d[i][j] = (int) (RRR * acos(0.5 * ((1.0 + q1) * q2 - (1.0 - q1) * q3)) + 1.0);
            d[j][i] = d[i][j];
        }
    return d;
}
```

I'm guessing that your problem was resulted from following the spec and using `nint` to calculate degree. But that is actually wrong. For example the input 10.53 means 10 degree and 53 minutes. But if you use the `nint` to round 10.53, then you'll get 11 degree, and subsequent computation of minute will also be wrong.